I want to create a material that refracts light but does not reflect it
I want to create a material that transmits and refracts light but does not mirror reflection
I don't want the environment textures set in the world to be reflective either
Is there a way to do this?
Both Eevee and Cycles would like to know if possible


Reflection from transparent objects happens because the refraction results in a ray bend so high that it doesn’t enter the object. To prevent reflection from refraction, you have to do something else with the rays. You can use a Frensel node to mix between a Glass shader and something else, but what that else is is up to you. A simpler solution would be to just use a transparency shader.

I want the refracted monkey object to be visible, but not the red cube. I can't IOR it if I use a transparent shader.I want the refracted monkey object to be visible, but not the red cube. I can't IOR it if I use a transparent shader

Or just use a Refraction BSDF node, see my answer.

If you only want refraction, use a Refraction BSDF (note: the environment seen here is not reflected, but refracted from below the monkey):

If you want the environment to disappear completely you have to go to the Render Properties > Film > Transparent and enable Transparent Glass additionally:

This was made in Cycles, in EEVEE I actually do not know how to keep the background invisible through the refraction because there is no Transparent Glass option in the Film settings, so I could only get the first result - and I have to admit I do not use EEVEE.

Oh! I did not know there was such a shader! However, it seems to show reflection probes. I understand you are not using EEVEE, is there any way to turn it off for this object only?

@InamuraJIN I'm sorry, no I have no idea. As I said I cannot even remove the background from transmission. I was just going with this answer because you asked for both EEVEE and Cycles solutions and I thought, well at least I have one for Cycles. Even there it has its limitations, on low angles the backside is black (because otherwise there would be a reflection). There are surely more refined solutions where you can maybe mix in transparency with Fresnel etc. but then you have a weird transition between refracted and unrefracted transmission which I could not get to get smooth so far.
